# java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0//files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied

Tags: java, android, native, ffimageloading

I am getting below error while converting picture in Android for some device

```
2021-08-31 16:34:12.293 18841-19661/ E/FFmpeg: Exception while trying to run: [Ljava.lang.String;@3739148
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/data/user/0//files/ffmpeg": error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1050)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:699)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:564)
        at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.ShellCommand.run(ShellCommand.java:10)
        at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:38)
        at com.github.hiteshsondhi88.libffmpeg.FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.doInBackground(FFmpegExecuteAsyncTask.java:10)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:133)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:141)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Comment: Maybe it's because of `//` that don't find ?

Comment: `"/data/user/0/<package>/files/ffmpeg"` getFilesDir()/ffmpeg.

Comment: what's the version of android in the devices you are getting error